# What are the arguments against using a JavaScript Framework for a Web site development company?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, yui

Our company builds websites and web applications.  We are a small firm and our team of developers are always building the javascript functions from scratch or copying from other websites built by us.  Every time I bring to the table the word standardization and using a JS framework like JQuery, Prototype or any other, I am told Frameworks  have the three points below as arguments against them:

- Mainly for people that don't know enough JS
- Frameworks limit Javascript developers
- Frameworks bloat the actual development code with a lot of things that are not used.
- We don't use enough Javascript in our applications for us to need JS framework

In my mind it seems that Frameworks, give our team a good starting point, documentation, a community and always the option to grow on top of the framework.  Could some Framework users elaborate further?

EDIT 1:

Thanks to all of you for your great responses.  I really did not think that this was going to be such a hot topic.  I am glad I asked the question.  I posted another similar question in the following link in case you might think you want to add something.  The topic of the new question is [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245893/what-are-the-arguments-against-using-a-css-framework) related.  Thanks.

Comment: Your coworkers prefer cut and paste over using a tested and evolving library? Have you considered seeking work elsewhere?

Comment: That really dont make any sense, you end up writting a lot of code (because of the abstraction you lose over the browser type), if Opera do this else if Chrome do this, elsif FF do that else if IE do a totally diferent thing =P.

Comment: Geo, show your team the answers to this post, but preface it by saying that StackOverflow is a collection of the world's best developers, the vast majority of whom defend frameworks as nothing short of common sense.  Then see what they say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arguments against:

- Frameworks prevent you from re-inventing the wheel
- Frameworks generally contain well tested code
- Frameworks are well supported by the community
- Frameworks force you to focus on the business problem you're trying to solve

</sarcasm>

- Frameworks may have a license you don't agree/can't work with

Comment: As someone who got burned badly by the Lightswitch and Angular js retirements I am wary of frameworks. But I've used a lot of them and would use them again. I'm just very careful about what I choose.

Answer (score 13):

By your coworkers point of view, .NET and JAVA are for people who don't know enough assembly.

Frameworks exist for a reason.  They allow you go focus on the problem instead of dealing with repetitive code.  They allow you to be confident (assuming you use well tested frameworks) that certain pieces of your code are reliable and well tested.

If your coworkers are against frameworks, I would seriously consider moving on.

Comment: Agree. Should this be an comment..instead of answer?

Comment: @Cody: I agree with you 100%, I am looking for the arguments against to obtain the whole picture of the two sided coins.  I am really tempted to choose your answer as the answer, but I was hoping for the points against the idea.

Answer (score 8):

Since no one has mentioned it - a Javascript framework rapidly becomes one more project dependancy, and in general terms, dependencies are bad as they represent points of failure.

As for this:

- Mainly for people that don't know
  enough JS

Without elaborating, I will say that if one of our team said something like that in my presence, I would try to shrug it off as a joke. If I thought they were being serious, I would probably have to kill them.

And as for this:

- Frameworks limit Javascript
  developers

That could translate to *"Frameworks make it marginally harder to write spaghetti code, and that's what I do best"*

Those are not arguments, they are excuses.

Comment: True as your point may be, a js library is no more a dependency than a stylesheet or image.  This should never become an issue with a project that has been organized to treat js files as a resource similar to images and css.  just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Ikarii Warrior - I'm not in any way opposed to JS libraries but in my opinion (and being a little pedantic) they do represent a point of failure. For example, a brand-new browser was released yesterday, and today management needs it to be supported. Relying on a community (or a vendor) for writing in support is, strictly speaking, a point of failure.

Comment: From the perspective of support, then yes it could be considered another point of failure and is certainly a valid point - I'm not trying to discredit your input. :)  That being said home growing your own javascript does not protect you from new browser compatibility issues.

Answer (score 6):

A few positives for javascript frameworks (like JQuery).

1. They provide standardization in ui
   elements.
2. Reduce time to develop complex
   interfaces and effects.
3. Normalize efforts by providing
   functions that are already
   cross-browser compatible.
4. Due to efforts in cross
   compatibility documentation is more
   useful in a framework as you can use
   the framework's api as canon
   instead of searching for obscure
   support for various/proprietary
   javascript functions.
5. Reduced learning curve for new
   developers making them productive on
   your software quicker.

I completely disagree that a framework limits javascript developers.  Quite the opposite actually.  Most frameworks provide extensive plug-in mechanisms where the framework can be extended using raw javascript utilizing hooks in the framework itself.

Comment: jQuery makes working in JavaScript actually pleasant.  The capacity for high-level construction of manipulations, effects, etc. allows the programmer to focus on the desired interaction rather than the minutiae of JS and browser compatibility.

Comment: Interesting to note that JQuery is still the second most commonly used framework behind React. I used it in a new project recently because I knew that when I move on the client will find it easy to find a developer that understands the code. If I'd been thinking of myself I'd have learned another flashy new framework instead.

Answer (score 5):

I'll use jQuery as an example, but what I'm saying here could apply to most JavaScript frameworks.

Many frameworks (notably jQuery) are far too monolithic and not modular enough.

While depending on well-tested 3rd party software is often more than justified, "frameworks" tend to give you a lot more functionality than you need at the moment.

In many projects, I very much like the convenience that jQuery gives me for selecting sets of elements (using $(".classname"), for example).  But, if I'm not using any significant amount of AJAX, I don't need the AJAX utilities provided by jQuery.

Software should do one thing and do it well, and software written in JavaScript is no exception.  Most of the frameworks you refer to try to do *everything*, resulting in unnecessary complexity.

One place this can bite you is when you're considering upgrading to the next version of the framework.  That involves crawling through jQuery's changelogs for backwards-incompatible changes and searching your project for areas where that code is used.  This can be quite a nightmare, especially if you don't necessarily have a comprehensive list of which jQuery features you use and which ones you don't.

Also, jQuery (and other frameworks) tends to cause developers to start depending on new features of jQuery without even thinking about it, making it harder to determine which features of jQuery your project uses and which it doesn't.

If you use a utility which does *one* thing, then you know exactly which features of that utility you're using.  There's only one.  (If you aren't using that utility at all, it's easy to determine.  Such a determination would mean you could safely remove it from your project.)

I'm all for using well-tested 3rd party code.  But if it tries to do too much, (that is, if it's a framework rather than a utility), you should probably look for an alternative.  If it tries to do too much (like jQuery tries to do too much), then it's got some serious, foundational design flaws that will probably come back to bite you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised no one has already mentioned it:

- A lot of web developers default to using JQuery without considering the alternatives
- And end up including it on a web page to do a few trivial tasks which could easily be done in pure JavaScript
- The result is that users have to wait for the whole library to download and it slows down web browsing

Also:

- Some web developers get carried away with the design of web pages, and end up developing unnecessarily complex web pages because of the power of JQuery
- Just because JQuery enables you to create scripts with good cross-browser compatibility it doesn't mean that the end result is usable on different devices / interfaces
- I'd also argue the cross-browser compatibilty because I've seen instances of webkit not playing well with JQuery
- JQuery encourages "fast" scripting - but if you rush it you are likely to have missed something out
- Writing in JavaScript from scratch is slower - but I believe that you end up with a more complete solution which more closely matches the users needs
- Using JQuery can shift the focus of the web developer to creating web sites which are highly graphical and visually appealing, whereas the focus should be on functionality and usability
- JQuery is not a silver bullet for web development

I am biased here because I don't use JQuery, but it is because I haven't found a need for it yet - maybe it's because I focus more on usability and functionality rather than making the user interface look pretty (sorry I know JQuery can do more than that).

Comment: I couldn't do a hundredth of the things I do if I dumped 70KB of framework dependency on to any or all of my projects. Thanks for having the integrity to speak out against jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

An argument against libraries is BROWSER SUPPORT most libraries support only a subset of browsers out there .
[Here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/ouh-shiny-bbcs-glow-is-finally-out) is an example of BBC rolling out their own instead of using something like jquery .

Comment: I agree, if you need to support some really way-out browser, frameworks might not be the best choice. That being said, they often realistically support just the right browsers.

Comment: Glow (from the bbc) is an option. They decided to move away from jQuery as they had to support some real legacy clients. The lib is very similar to jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I liked the answer of pb +

> Mainly for people that don't know
>   enough JS

I believe it is too complicated for them, so they use this excuse. FW allows you to build much more complex applications.

> Frameworks limit Javascript developers

bullshit

> Frameworks bloat the actual
>   development code with a lot of things
>   that are not used.

what is it today extra 100k-200k? especially if you use the CDN versions (at google for instance). And this is assuming you use nothing in the FW.

Comment: 100-200 k? jq is only 26k down the wire when you use the min version together with gzip.

Comment: This is the max, not everybody uses the min versions.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of good reasons to be suspicious of frameworks in general, balanced of course by lots of reasons why they are worthwhile.

I use jquery now, and frankly within an hour of learning it realised that it fits the job so well that if it didn't exist I'd only end up reimplementing something very similar myself, only it wouldn't be as good or as cross platform.

There isn't much bloat there, it's very small and well designed and does nothing at all that stops you writing any javascript you want for specific cases that don't fit your needs.