# What are the arguments against using a CSS Framework?

Tags: css, frameworks, blueprint-css

Yesterday I asked a question here that got more momentum that what I thought it would.  Here is the question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242528/what-are-the-arguments-against-using-a-javascript-framework-for-a-web-site-develo) since it is related.  I am interested now in the possibility of that using two frameworks together will be worst than using a JS framework and CSS from scratch or the other way around.

The question is clear, if you think there are arguments against using a CSS framework like [Blueprint CSS](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) please tell me what you think they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main argument is that CSS is not really a programming language. A framework is meant to include reusable functions and data structures. CSS has neither of these constructs. A CSS "framework" is more akin to a template in a word processor. It provides ready-done design work, but it also imposes more constraints than starting from a blank slate.

Incidentally, this was what drove the development of [Compass](http://wiki.github.com/chriseppstein/compass). It's similar to a CSS framework, but instead it uses the CSS metalanguage [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), which does have functions and variables. Thus rather than (for example) having columns baked into the framework, you can write something like `+columns(5) +column-margins(1em)` and it will generate the appropriate CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Browser compatibility? We're continually struggling to maintain IE6 support for the 1/3 of our clients that cannot or will not upgrade. Lots of CSS issues.

Comment: From your response I understand that you are currently using a CSS framework and that is why you are struggling to maintain IE6 users.  Is that right?

Comment: We haven't even gotten that far. We're trying to do some 'modern' CSS-y stuff like sprites with little success in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

I use the YUI CSS libraries, but I'm not sure if that counts as a framework.

YUI handles the basics for fonts, layout (grids) and other formatting and makes it consistent across browsers and Operating Systems. It's under a free software license, also.

They also have a very useful [interactive grid designer](http://patorjk.com/blog/2009/07/12/typing-distance/).